# Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'View not found [name, type, prefix]: search, feed, searchView'

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.8

Here is the complete error :

> Exception: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'View not found
>   [name, type, prefix]: search, feed, searchView' in
>   /httpdocs/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php:847

Stack trace is as follows:

> in Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController::getView called at
>   /httpdocs/libraries/src/MVC/Controller/BaseController.php (621) in
>   Joomla\CMS\MVC\Controller\BaseController::display called at
>   /httpdocs/components/com_search/controller.php (34)

What error is related and how can i solve it ? Is it because of the article pages that doesnot exist ?

Comment: Could you include your code? What do you expect to see? What have you tried?

Comment: here is the code thats giving error :

Comment: $document = \JFactory::getDocument();
  $viewType = $document->getType();
  $viewName = $this->input->get('view', $this->default_view);
  $viewLayout = $this->input->get('layout', 'default', 'string');

  $view = $this->getView($viewName, $viewType, '', array('base_path' => $this->basePath, 'layout' => $viewLayout));

  // Get/Create the model
  if ($model = $this->getModel($viewName))
  {
   // Push the model into the view (as default)
   $view->setModel($model, true);
  }

  $view->document = $document;